# C++: Trying to add very large ints together in a binary to decimal converter multiple times while your input is with a string value

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
template <class Type>
string MyStack<Type>::binaryToDecimal2(string n)
{
//variable declaration and initialization
string dec = "";
MyStack<string> stk;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++)
{
    string s = to_string((n[i] - '0') * pow(2, (n.length() - i - 1)));
    stk.push(s);
}
while (!stk.isEmptyStack()){
    string item;
    item = stk.top();
    stk.pop();
    cout << item << endl;
}
return dec;
}
```

How would I be able to change binaryToDecimal2 in order to successfully add together my strings together without losing data? I've tried making the elements that I'm adding together unsigned ints, but the values that I am getting aren't correct if the value is too large.[image]

In the photo you enter a binary number, and the line that says the equivalent decimal num is: is when I use integers. The numbers with lots of decimals is when it is being outputted from my stack inside the while loop. How would I be able to add all of those numbers and put them in dec to be outputted?

Comment: Could you add sample inputs and expected output as well?

Comment: Can you test cases for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

1) Is the result inaccurate or completely wrong? How large must the number be in order to be "too large"?
I cannot run your code as it is incomplete, `num` is defined but never used. If you try to assign a number larger than 2³² it cannot be captured by `num` of course.

2) std::pow returns a floating point number, which you then convert to a string. After executing

```
std::string n = "10100";
std::vector<std::string> stk;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++)
{
    std::string s = std::to_string((n[i] - '0') * std::pow(2, (n.length() - i - 1)));
    stk.push_back(s);
}
```

`stk` is

```
16.000000                                                                                                                    
0.000000                                                                                                                     
4.000000                                                                                                                     
0.000000                                                                                                                     
0.000000
```

But I am pretty sure `findSum` expects the passed strings not to contain dots.

Comment: As I assumed, you process floats because of the pow function. Convert them to integers before putting them into a string. The number you entered in the image above is between 2^31 and 2^32, which is already to large for a int, but not for an unsigned int. But if you enter one more digit it's over with uint, too. Why not simply long long or uint64_t everywhere?